# How to search a pattern with the help of curly braces and add / remove from pattern?

Tags: regex, vim, substitution

I can't find out how to resolve this:

I'm trying to search a pattern p.e. '`test`' with the help of Curly braces
p.e. `test\{2,}`

I want to add or remove to/from the same pattern using an inputdialog.

p.e.
find the word `test` {2,} times and remove 1 test from match
or find the word `test` {2,3} times and remove 2 x test from match
or find the word `test` {,2} times and add 2 x test to match

I can't find a regex to do what I want.
Does anyone know a solution?

**EDIT**
Maybe splitting the submatch string in a list is a solution and count the number of matches (the length of the list).
p.e. searching `test\{2,5}` and removing 2 x test:

```
%s/\(test\)\@<!\(test\)\{2,5}\(test\)\@!/\=repeat(submatch(2), len(split(submatch(2), 'test'))-2)/g
```

but this doesn't work.
What did I wrong?

Comment: Use `(test){2}` (etc.) to match occurrences of the entire word. Since the parenthesis only surround the single word, you can use `\1` (or your local equivalent thereof) in replacement expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.
You can do it with a general regex.

The solution was to split the searchstring and count how many matches there are and after knowing how many matches there are you can add or remove from these matches.

**regex**:

```
%s/\(test\)\@<!\(test\)\{2,5}\(test\)\@!/\=repeat(submatch(2), len(split(submatch(0), '\ze'.submatch(2)))+2)/g
```

explication:

- search `test` between 2 and 5 times but not whitin a string of more `test`:

  `\(test\)\@<!\(test\)\{2,5}\(test\)\@!`
- find how many times `test` is found in entire match:

  `len(split(submatch(0), '\ze'.submatch(2))`

  splitting the entire match by a nr. of single matches and count the single matches

  submatch(0) = multiple 'test' (entire match)
   submatch(2) = 'test'
- repeat the nr. of matches from within the entire match and add or remove to/from it:

  `\=repeat(submatch(2), len(split(submatch(0), '\ze'.submatch(2)))+2)`

Answer (score 1):

You need to enclose your string (`test`) in escaped parentheses so that it will operate as one unit. That gives you `\(test\)\{2,}`, which will find `testtest`, `testtesttest`, etc.

To replace that with just one `test`, try this:

`:%s/\(test\)\{2,}/\1/g`

That searches for 2 or more repetitions of `test` and uses `\1` to replace it with a single instances of the search string.

Similarly, for your second request, just put the `3` in:

`:%s/\(test\)\{2,3}/\1/g`

And for the third request, just stick in more copies of `\1` to get your desired output:

`:%s/\(test\)\{,2}/\1\1\1/g`

Comment: You're right about the missing parens, but Vim syntax for match ranges is indeed `\{n,m}`; unlike other regexp dialects like sed's.

Comment: @IngoKarkat Odd; it appears to be optional in vim. I never knew. I'll edit my post.

Comment: e.g the 2nd request. if I had `testtest`, the replaced result would be `""` empty string. if I understood right.

Comment: @Kent, you might be right. That would be `:%s/\(test\)\{2}\(test\)\?/\2/g`

Comment: If it matters to you, you can get rid of a bunch of those backslashes using the `\v` atom.  Thus, for patrickvacek's first regex, an equivalent expression would be `:%s/\v(test){2,}/\1/g`, which is a little easier to read IMO.

Comment: @patrickvacek, thanx for answering. However it is not exactly what I want. I want not replace it with 1 x test or 3 x test but removing 1 test from match. p.e. the 1st example.. If there is a match of 4x test it has to return 3 x test (remove 1x test). If there is a match of 3x test it has to return 2x test (remove 1x test).

Comment: @Remonn, I think I understand your intention better, but I'm going to have to keep thinking about it to see if I can figure out a clean way to do it. I don't have anything off the top of my head; I don't think there's a native mechanism for repeating replacements like that.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirement right, the answer may help.

**I would use `test(space)` in examples, and the example has ending space**

> - *find the word test {2,} times and remove 1 test from match*

```
[before ]test test foo test test test foo test 
[command]s/\v(test )(\1+)/\2/g
[after  ]test foo test test foo test
```

> - *find the word test {2,3} times and remove 2 x test from match*

```
[before ]test test foo test test test foo test 
[command]s/\v(test ){2}(\1?)/\2/g
[after  ]foo test foo test
```

> - *find the word test {,2} times and add 2 x test to match*

```
[before ]test test foo test test test foo test 
[command]s/\v(test ){,2}/&\1\1/g
[after  ]test test test test foo test test test test test test test foo test test test
```

Comment: Thanks Ken, you've found the answer for my examples. What I would like to do is to find a general regex what works in every example. Is there no way to generalize the regex? (I want to use an input dialog to insert. p.e. find `test\{2,5}` and remove 2x test from match or whatever other example. I've tried it with submatches but it didn't work out as I wanted. The problem is that I don't know how many times there is a match with `test`

Comment: @Remonn I doubt there is a generic regex/:s command to do what you want. however you could parse user's input, e.g. `test{2,5} and remove 2x`, to generate a `:s` command. or generate different arguments for `substitute()`.  for this example, user want to remove `2x`, so the `2` is interesting for us, we need `s/\v(foo){2}...`, and user gave `{2,5}`, you have to compare the lower bound (2) and the delete input (2), in this case they are same. so `5-2=3` we have `s/\v(foo){2}(\1{,3})/\2/g`

Comment: Kent, thank you. The first `{2}` is the lower bound and the curly braces after `\1` is `{2,5} - 2 = {,3}`? I hope it works. Will try to test a few more examples as `{1,3}` :)

Comment: Hmm doesn't work with `{1,3}`.. Another solution I'm thinking at is to split the matches in a list (dividing by the search self (test) and count the number of entries in the list. Would this be possible?